# python serial port code is working in windows but not in linux

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyserial

i have wrote some python code that is working fine in windows but it is not working in linux (ubuntu 12.04).
Im getting this message:

```
File "mygui.py", line 50, in sendPacket
returnpacket = str(length) + str(com3.read(ord(length)-1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

here is my code:

```
import serial
import crc16pure
import time

def main():
#works for 115200, 250000, 500000, 1000000
com3 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=1000000,dsrdtr=False)
com3.timeout = 10
time.sleep(5) #MUST wait this long before writing, otherwise the serial
#p = '{"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",{"  ",{"iget",{null}}}}'
p = '{"SensorNodeUUID":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","SlaveUUID":"  ","Command":"iget","Args":null}'
#discard first byte
com3.read()
timesum = 0
lstart = time.clock()

for i in range(3):
#print("writing packet")
start = time.clock()
#print(preparepacket(p))
com3.write(preparepacket(p))

length = com3.read()


returnpacket = str(length) + str(com3.read(ord(length)-1))
print(returnpacket)
com3.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not done serial in years, and I've since written bufsock...  You might try bufsock to see if it helps your situation:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/bufsock.html

It'll deal with things like waiting until a byte is ready, before giving up on a read.  I've used on Cygwin, but never native Windows Python.  But it's known to work on CPython 2.x, CPython 3.x, Jython and Pypy on *ix.

Don't let the name fool you - I wrote it for buffering sockets, but it works fine for file handles too.